# Solve each of the following recurrences using the Iteration Method:

Tags: iteration, recurrence

1. T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1, T(0) = 1 
   how to solve it 
   Solve each of the following recurrences using the Iteration Method:

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please stop by the [help] and read [ask]. At the least, you should tag a language.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you can do it like this

```
int t[n + 1];
t[0] = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
    t[i] = 2 * t[i - 1] + 1;
}
```